# Arbitrage and completeness in multiperiod model?

Tags: stochastic-processes, arbitrage, asset-pricing, homework

[image]

Given a 2-period market with above stock price process along with a riskfree stock with a return of 5%, how do I determine whether the market is arbitrage-free and complete when I only have knowledge of one-period models? Is it enough to determine whether each of the 3 one-period models are arbitrage and complete? And if so, why?

Comment: Aren't you missing something in the question?  I think they are giving you an options question.  You have to figure out the fair value for a call or a put based on this binomial tree.  And the stock is not riskfree - there is a riskfree rate.  I think you might have misread the q.